# Dojo how to load a theme?

Tags: dojo

I want to use a theme in dojo, dojox and dijit. For example tundra. Do I need only the line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dojo/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css" />
```

or are more css imports needed to get all the styles that I need?

Do I need to import specific css for widgets like dialog?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add it to the body as well:

```
<body class="tundra">
```

I think that's it: class + proper CSS link.

The class hints at how to use different themes for different parts of a page. Just put the proper class on the parent of a sub-tree where you want to see the theme.